# How can I minimize stirring when blending whole fruits?

Tags: juicing

1. I usually quarter whole fruits, and toss them into my Vitamix blender.
2. But it blends only one or two quarters, and can't impact the other quarters. Then I stir the Suspension with my stick.

[image]

3. The blender again blends only one or two quarters, and I must repeat step  2.
4. I usually must repeat step 2 at least 4 more times, before all the quarters are liquefied. [image]

Answer (score 5):

If you don't add additional liquid, you will likely need to stir.  That is the reason Vitamix includes the plunger. So, if you want to minimize stirring, you will need to add additional liquid to allow the whole pieces to remain in contact with the blades.

Comment: Actually, many people misunderstand the blender. It is designed for liquids! It can work if no liquid is added, but only with more effort (in this case plunger) and some risk for the motor - or, with weaker blenders, with simply bad results. So yes, your answer is right, the intended usage is to blend liquids, not solids.

Comment: @rumtscho If the motor is strong enough, the whole thing can explode, too. Happened to me once, the glass was nicely distributed through the room and I kept finding pieces for months afterwards. :)